# Tablesorter and dynamically added rows

Tags: javascript, sorting, dynamic, pagination, tablesorter

I'm having trouble with tablesorter and dynamically added rows.  When I try to add my rows, I get this error:
`config.parsers[j] is undefined.`

I'm adding the rows the same way as in the example here, http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-pager.html.

```
delete_rows();
var html_data = '';
for ( i in wos ) {
    html_data += '<tr>';
    html_data += '<td><a href="#" class="get_wo" title="' + wos[i].val1 + '">' + wos[i].val1 + '</a></td>';
    html_data += '<td>' + wos[i].val2 + '</td>';    
    html_data += '</tr>';
}

var $html_data=$(html_data);
wo.show();                  
$( "#wo_table" ).find('tbody').append($html_data).trigger('addRows', [$html_data]);
```

First I delete all the rows in my table except for the headers, then I create and append the rows to the table.

Has anyone ever had the same problem or a similar problem?
I'm using Tablesorter version 2.0.25.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're removing all of the table rows then using the "addRows" method, because it will just add the new rows under the original rows. So, since ALL of the rows are removed first, it would be better to use the "update" method like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/9sKwJ/5/); click the "test" button):

```
$( "#wo_table" ).find('tbody').append($html_data).trigger('update');
```

Oh, and I didn't see that error you mentioned at all.

Comment: I'm removing all the rows since its used as a search, and if they search for something else I have to remove the old results.  This does not work with the pagination, it only displays the first 10 results and the remaining results do not show up.  I think its because the update function for Tablesorter since not all the rows are present when the pager is called

Comment: Ok, it wasn't clear that you were using the pager, even though you linked to it ;)... try setting the pager option `removeRows` to `false`, or use `$('table').trigger('destroy.pager');` before updating and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far fudgey, right now my table works except for 1 thing.  When I change the pager to show more/less results per page, then try to sort the results, it reverts back to the old amount of results per page.  I think its because I'm not updating the pager correctly.

Comment: Hmmm, I see you said you're using the latest version of tablesorter, but are you using the latest version of the pager plugin? It used to behave like that, but I thought I updated it.

Comment: I was using mottie's version of tablesorter.  Changed back to Christian's tablesorter and everything works fine now.  Thanks for the help fudgey!

Comment: Sorting does not work in your fiddle (at least that is the case in IE9).